# Mean curvature of compact surface not homeomorphic to a sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I'm using Do Carmo's book to self-study differential geometry, where I encounter Exercise 1 on page 282 (Section 4-5), which talks about the Gaussian curvature of points on the surface.

I'm wondering whether the conclusion can be generalized to mean curvature. For instance, for any compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that's not homeomorphic to a sphere, does there always exist a point with zero mean curvature, i.e $H=0$?

Comment: You should make your question self-contained, as lots of people don’t have DoCarmo's book. So, if you try to modify your argument for $K$, what happens? Please edit the question appropriately with your progress.

Comment: Hi Ted! Basically I just want to check whether the claim below is true or not: any compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that's not homeomorphic to a sphere always contains a point with zero mean curvature, i.e $H=0$

Comment: So how would you attack this question? How is this related to DoCarmo's exercise, and how did you do that exercise? I want you to do some work here.

Comment: Umm....I guess for my generalization here...you can basically construct a minimal surface that's not homeomorphic to a sphere?

Comment: Totally not relevant. You’re asking for $H=0$ at a point, not everywhere. And there are no compact minimal surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$; why?

Comment: Oh I see...sorry I forgot some essential facts about minimal surface

Comment: Oh I see....I remember proving that there's no compact minimal surface as some exercise in Do Carmo's book (around chapter 3)...umm....

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi Professor Shifirn, would you mind giving me some of your thoughts on this claim? I have tried several examples, and I believed that the conclusion should be false. There's probably some counter-example (like some "torus")?

Comment: Please do not delete your questions, especially when someone has gone to the effort of commenting and/or writing an answer for you. This is quite unfriendly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your hunch is right. Take a very long, thin torus. What do you think about $g\ge 2$?